# How can I update a progress bar with howler js?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar, dom-events, howler.js

How can I use howler js and update the progress bar as the audio plays?

I assume I use either `pos` or `seek` however I can't seem to get it working.

Can I create a `on` event listener to change every time the position changes?

Progress bar HTML:

```
<progress id="progress_bar" value="0.0" max="1.0" style="-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none; height: 48px; float: left;"></progress>
```

Howler js:

```
on ('update_progress', function() {
    document.getElementById('progress_bar').value = audio.pos();
}),
```

and then how can I update the position of the audio if the progress bar is pressed. I think I might actually be better served using an input range in that case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no progress event in howler.js, though it may get added at a later date. However, you can get the current position by calling `audio.seek()` at any time (on 2.0) or `audio.pos()` on 1.0. You could then either call this in `requestAnimationFrame` (this is what the 2.0 demos use) or `setInterval` to update your progress bar.

Comment: Will look into this and post my result. May I ask also what the syntax is for custom on event. I thought it was this `on("mute", function());` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you using 2.0? There is no mute event on 1.x.

Comment: Please use `requestAnimationFrame` as this will perform better when your tab isn't the currently focused tab.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following snippet

```
setInterval(() => {
  updateWidth(); 
},300);

function updateWidth() {
  if (sound.playing()) {
    let width = (sound.seek()/sound.duration())*100;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be Multiplied by 100 not divided.

`let width = (sound.seek()/sound.duration())*100;`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Vikram's answer, but using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`.

```js
// Set a play callback for the howl
howl.on("play", () => {

    // Reference
    let updateRaf = undefined;

    // Define a function to be run on every animation frame
    const onAnimationFrame = () => {

        // If the howl is still playing
        if (howl.playing()) {

            // Calculate the width
            const width = (howl.seek() / howl.duration()) * 100;

            // Continue processing updates
            updatedRaf = requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
        }

        // If the howl is no longer playing
        else {

            // Stop processing updates
            if (updatedRaf) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(updatedRaf);
            }
        }
    };

    // Start processing updates
    updatedRaf = requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
});
```

Note: Not tested.